# How to stop apache2 service

Tags: 14.04, apache2, cron, upstart

I need to stop apache2 service for 3 hours during the backup time.
How can I do this through `crontab` or similar ways...

I tried with crontab:

```
15 14 * * * service apache2 stop
```

But nothing happens.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried to command in a terminal? Why don't you use `systemctl stop apache2`?

Comment: What kind of backup? I mean why not stopping Apache before backup script and then starting after?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? `service` is used with Upstart (deprecated), `systemctl` (mentioned by @xenoid) with Systemd.

Comment: @Melebius - ubuntu 14

Comment: @madneon we using ralus. Ralus gives to us next message: Error: Could not start Pre Job Command

Comment: @xenoid the command service apache2 start works on command line.. but not with crontab.  I will try with systemctl

Comment: @vladadj31I don't know this software, how is this backup process starting?

Comment: @madneon It's scheduled via Ralus.  I don't have permission to test Ralus, so, only know that Ralus have pre backup commands and post backup commands, and this is mandatory for me to use Ralus.

Comment: You need to run `service apache2 stop` as root to make it work, right? Does Ralus run as root?

Comment: @Melebius yes, right. Ralus run as root as well.

Comment: You would need to use the pre-job commands to run `service apache2 stop` and post-job commands to run `service apache2 start` as root. However, I'm not familiar with Ralus to help in setting it up, but since Ralus offers this functionality as you mentioned, that's the best option. Using crontabs can't be reliable in this case, because a backup might take more (or less) than 3 hours.

Comment: @Dan  I agree, but pre and post job commands don't work - I don't know the reason because I don't have access for this part of the server (I'm Drupal programmer and administrator don't shared details with me). Afterwards, without Ralus, what is the best solution for make backup for Drupal sites, cron job?

Comment: But why you need to stop whole Apache anyways? If you need to dump Drupal (or any) database you can do it without stopping whole thing. If the Apache hosts some public pages its [very] bad idea to stop it.

Comment: @madneon because Ralus, when make the backup, don't do that on the right way - e.g. backup is not finishing and we got an error from Ralus about MySQL: Unable to open the item 
[ServerName][ROOT]/var/lib/mysql/databasename/tablename.ibd - skipped.

Comment: @vladadj31 so its not Apache the problem but MySQL, right? To backup it, you probably should use `mysql_dump`.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to execute in terminalas root:

```
service apache2 stop && backup_software && service apache2 start
```

Comment: You're missing an `&&` in there - the command will fail in its current state.

Comment: sorry i totally forgot it, added now

Comment: Changed it from systemctl to service which should work with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: [OP states](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094217/how-to-stop-apache2-service#comment1801753_1094217): “the command service apache2 start works on command line.. but not with crontab.” How does your answer solve this problem?

Comment: OP also states that he needs to stop apache just for the backup process and than start it again and the purpose of the crontab was so that apache can start after the backup, so my answer stops apache, executes the backup program and than starts apache after the backup process finishes. That's how

Comment: I suggest changing last `&&` to `;` to make sure Apache starts again (unconditionally).